# JSON C# Web Service Creation and Testing?

Tags: c#, mysql, json, web-services

I am trying to create a JSON WCF web service. 
I'm totally unclear on the whole process really! I'm connecting to MySQL DB on my Server.
So I have the following code:
My Interface -

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/GetAllResources")]
        List<Resources> GetAllResources();


        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/AddRoom")]
        void AddRoom(string location, string name);
...
```

My Service -

```
[ScriptService]
        public class Service1 : IService1
    {

            [WebMethod]
            [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
            public void AddRoom(string location, string name)
            {
                String conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                using (MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(conString))
                {
                    cnn.Open();
                    String sql = String.Format("INSERT INTO rooms(roomLocation, roomName) VALUES ({0}, {1});", location, name);
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cnn);
                    //doesn't return any rows
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }              
            }

            [WebMethod]
            [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
            public List<Resources> GetAllResources()
            {
                String conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                List<Resources> al = new List<Resources>();
                using (MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(conString))
                {
                    cnn.Open();
                    String sql = String.Format("select * from resources");
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cnn);
                    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        al.Add((Resources)reader[0]);
                    }
                    return al;
                }
            }
...
```

Web Config -

```
...
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RoomBookingService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="RoomBookingServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="../Service1.svc"
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            contract="RoomBookingService.IService1"
            behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RoomBookingServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehaviour">
          <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
...
```

Is this correct?? What tools can I use to test the service? I have dropped it onto the server and tried downloading a few testing tools but they don't give me any errors just that it's not returning JSON?!

I will be creating an Android app to talk to the Service, but as this will also be a learning curve I want to know that my service works correctly before adding in another layer of complexity.

Any help or comments on my code or my issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time

Comment: you can use a tool like fiddler to test the service. do you add content-type : json in your service call?

Comment: Thanks. Ok I'll check out Fiddler. No, I have been using software to test such as Rest-Client-Master and JSON-WebService-Tester-Master. So I wasn't specifying the content-type. I was just wanting to see the json being returned.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working:
Here is my code:
**Contract:**

```
    namespace RoomBookingService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "GetAllResources")]
        String GetAllResources();
```

**Service**

```
[WebMethod]
            [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public String GetAllResources()
            {
                String conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> tableRows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row= new Dictionary<string,object>();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer =
          new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

                try
                {
                    using (MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(conString))
                                    {                                        
                                        cnn.Open();
                                        String sql = String.Format("select resourceID, resourceName, resourceDesc, roomID from resources");
                                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cnn);
                                        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                                        dt.Load(reader);

                                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                                        {
                                            row = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
                                            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                                            {
                                                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                                            }
                                            tableRows.Add(row);
                                        }
                                        return serializer.Serialize(tableRows);
                                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return ex.ToString();
                }            
            }
```

**WebConfig**

```
 <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RoomBookingService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="RoomBookingServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            contract="RoomBookingService.IService1"
            behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RoomBookingServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehaviour">
          <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
```

Still not absultely clear on everything but it's working!! So I'll go with that :-)

Thanks!